# Problemas con la etiqueta <nav>

Tags: html5, css3, backend, frontend

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy intentando aprender css y html por mi cuenta, lastimosamente tengo un problema. Cuando uso la etiqueta nav (ver ejemplo) los elementos que tengo dentro de la etiqueta se ven desorganizados y no logro entender porque, he revisado mis estilos y también la forma en que están organizados, me ayude también con la etiqueta float:left; para poder ubicarlos pero aún así tampoco quedan bien. Estaría realmente agradecido si alguien me explica que sucede. Saludos y buen día

¿Cómo podría aprender mejor acerca de este error?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Propiedades de ubicación</title>
    <style>
        
        /*<!--SELECTOR UNIVERSAL ( ASTERISCO )-->*/
        
        *{    
            margin: 0;
        }
        header{
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 120px;
            background-color: #3A7CE1;
        }
        
        #logo{
            position: absolute;
            top: 30px;
            left: 30px;
        /*Es posible usar right y bottom*/
            width: 200px;
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        
        .redes{
            position: absolute;
            width: 42px;
            height: 42px;
            background-color:#000000;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        
        
        #Icono1{
            top: 42px;
            right: 120px;
            
        }
        
        #Icono2{
            top: 42px;
            right: 71px;
            
        }
        #Icono3{
            top: 42px;
            right: 19px;
            
        }
        nav{
            position:relative;
            margin:auto;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 48px;
            background:#18D8DB;
        }
        
        .botones{
            float:left;
            width: 196px;
            margin: 0px 2px;
            height: 48px;
            background:#DB1E21;
        }
        /*Top o parte superior*/ 
        
        #Top{
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 192px;
            background:#EF2023;
        }
        
        section{
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 453px;
            background-color:#B916DD;
            
        }
        
        footer{
            position: relative;
            margin: 20px auto;
            width: 1000px;
            height: 70px;
            background-color:#ECAC0A;
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
    <!--Inicia cabezote-->
    
    <header>
        <div id="logo"></div>
        
        <div id="Icono1" class="redes"></div>
        <div id="Icono2" class="redes"></div>
        <div id="Icono3" class="redes"></div>
    </header>
    
    <!--Cierra Cabezote-->
    
    <!--Inicia barra de Navegación-->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            
            <li class="botones"></li>   
            <li class="botones"></li>
            <li class="botones"></li>
            <li class="botones"></li>
            <li class="botones"></li>
            
        </ul>
        
    </nav>
    
    <!--Cierra barra de Navegación-->
    
    <!--Inicia parte superior-->
    
    <div id="Top">
        <ul>
            <li> </li>
            <li> </li>
            <li> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <!--Cierra parte superior-->
    
    <!--Inicia section-->
    
    <section>
        <aside id="izq"></aside>
        <article></article>
        <aside id="der"></aside>
    </section>
    <!--Cierra section-->
    
    <!--Iniciapie de página-->
    <footer></footer>
    <!--Cierra pie de página-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas, por favor explica mejor, que está mal, y como quisieras que se viese. Por que veo una lista que quieres meter al div, pero no entiendo como quieres que se vea.

Comment: He añadido una edición amigo, lo que quiero es que los elementos 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 queden organizados dentro de mi barra nav, sin embargo el 5 elemento se ve debajo del primero.

Answer (score 3):

El botón 5 flota correctamente a la izquierda, visualmente se ve debajo del 1 porque al no tener espacio a la derecha del 4 arma su propia "línea".

La falta de espacio está dada porque el elemento `ul` incluye un padding de manera predeterminada, quitando el padding del `ul` :

```
nav > ul { padding:0 }
```

los cálculos dan bien:

```
( 196px + 2px * 2  ) * 5 = 1000px
```

El `>` es un ["selector de hijo directo"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) y afectará sólo a los `ul` dentro de un `nav`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: #3A7CE1;
}

#logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  /*Es posible usar right y bottom*/
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.redes {
  position: absolute;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

#Icono1 {
  top: 42px;
  right: 120px;
}

#Icono2 {
  top: 42px;
  right: 71px;
}

#Icono3 {
  top: 42px;
  right: 19px;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #18D8DB;
}

nav>ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.botones {
  float: left;
  width: 196px;
  margin: 0px 2px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #DB1E21;
}


/*Top o parte superior*/

#Top {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 192px;
  background: #EF2023;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 453px;
  background-color: #B916DD;
}

footer {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #ECAC0A;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Propiedades de ubicación</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Inicia cabezote-->

  <header>
    <div id="logo"></div>

    <div id="Icono1" class="redes"></div>
    <div id="Icono2" class="redes"></div>
    <div id="Icono3" class="redes"></div>
  </header>

  <!--Cierra Cabezote-->

  <!--Inicia barra de Navegación-->
  <nav>
    <ul>

      <li class="botones">boton 1</li>
      <li class="botones">boton 2</li>
      <li class="botones">boton 3</li>
      <li class="botones">boton 4</li>
      <li class="botones">boton 5</li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

  <!--Cierra barra de Navegación-->

  <!--Inicia parte superior-->

  <div id="Top">
    <ul>
      <li>top 1</li>
      <li>top 2</li>
      <li>top 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <!--Cierra parte superior-->

  <!--Inicia section-->

  <section>
    <aside id="izq"></aside>
    <article></article>
    <aside id="der"></aside>
  </section>
  <!--Cierra section-->

  <!--Iniciapie de página-->
  <footer></footer>
  <!--Cierra pie de página-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente no te recomiendo utilices float, a menos que sea un caso muy particular, en el caso del nav lo que puedes hacer es usar un display flex o grid, pero como estas comenzando aprende primero flexbox y luego pasa a css grid, como resolver lo de tu nav, pues bueno con el siguiente código te puedes apoyar.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Etiqueta Nav</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 24px;
            }
            nav {
                max-width: 1200px;
                margin: auto;
            }
            .menu {
                list-style: none;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .menu li {
                width: 200px;
                padding: 10px 0;
                background-color: blue;
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="menu maximo">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda y tu solución, aprenderé más acerca de lo que mencionas. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo estas llamando a un identificador llamado "#Top" lo cual puede ser una palabra reservada dentro de los ámbitos de nombres.

Cambia el Nombre de top a tope por ejemplo:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Propiedades de ubicación</title>
<style>
    
    /*<!--SELECTOR UNIVERSAL ( ASTERISCO )-->*/
    
    *{    
        margin: 0;
    }
    header{
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 120px;
        background-color: #3A7CE1;
    }
    
    #logo{
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
        left: 30px;
    /*Es posible usar right y bottom*/
        width: 200px;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #000000;
    }
    
    .redes{
        position: absolute;
        width: 42px;
        height: 42px;
        background-color:#000000;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }
    
    
    #Icono1{
        top: 42px;
        right: 120px;
        
    }
    
    #Icono2{
        top: 42px;
        right: 71px;
        
    }
    #Icono3{
        top: 42px;
        right: 19px;
        
    }
    nav{
        position:relative;
        margin:auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 48px;
        background:#18D8DB;
    }
    
    .botones{
        float:left;
        width: 196px;
        margin: 0px 2px;
        height: 48px;
        background:#DB1E21;
    }
    /*Top o parte superior*/ 
    
    #Tope{
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 192px;
        background:#EF2023;
    }
    
    section{
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 453px;
        background-color:#B916DD;
        
    }
    
    footer{
        position: relative;
        margin: 20px auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 70px;
        background-color:#ECAC0A;
</style>
</head>

<body>

<!--Inicia cabezote-->

<header>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    
    <div id="Icono1" class="redes"></div>
    <div id="Icono2" class="redes"></div>
    <div id="Icono3" class="redes"></div>
</header>

<!--Cierra Cabezote-->

<!--Inicia barra de Navegación-->
<nav>
    <ul>
        
        <li class="botones"></li>   
        <li class="botones"></li>
        <li class="botones"></li>
        <li class="botones"></li>
        <li class="botones"></li>
        
    </ul>
    
</nav>

<!--Cierra barra de Navegación-->

<!--Inicia parte superior-->

<div id="Tope">
    <ul>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
        <li> </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!--Cierra parte superior-->

<!--Inicia section-->

<section>
    <aside id="izq"></aside>
    <article></article>
    <aside id="der"></aside>
</section>
<!--Cierra section-->

<!--Iniciapie de página-->
<footer></footer>
<!--Cierra pie de página-->
</body>
</html>
```